# Slick group by count

Tags: scala, slick

Let's say I have `organization`s, each organization has different `group`s, and `user`s subscribe to groups.

`case class OrganizationEntity(id: Option[Int], name: String)`

`case class GroupEntity(id: Option[Int], organizationId: Int, name: String)`

`case class GroupUserEntity(groupId: Int, userId: Int)`

I need to get all groups of an organization, with the organizationName, and the quantity of users subscribed to that group.

In SQL, this can be easily done with this query:

```sql
SELECT g.*, o.organizationname, COUNT(DISTINCT gu.userid) FROM `group` g
              LEFT JOIN organization o ON g.orgid = o.organizationid
              LEFT JOIN group_user gu ON g.groupid = gu.groupid
              WHERE g.orgid = 1234
              GROUP BY g.groupid;
```

But I am struggling to replicate that in slick,

I've started writing this, but I am stuck now:

```
def findByOrganizationId(organizationId: Int) = {
      (for {
        g <- groups if g.organizationId === organizationId
        o <- organizations if o.id === organizationId
        gu <- groupUsers if g.id === gu.groupid
      } yield (g, o.name, gu)).groupBy(_._3.groupid).map { case (_, values) => (values.map { case (g, orgname, users) => (g, orgname, users.) } }.result
    }
```

Comment: `.length` should do the trick

Answer (score 0):

You can just add `.length` to do the count in your code.

I think should also work directly in the yield so you don't need the `groupBy`:

```
def findByOrganizationId(organizationId: Int) = {
      (for {
        g <- groups if g.organizationId === organizationId
        o <- organizations if o.id === organizationId
        gu <- groupUsers if g.id === gu.groupid
      } yield (g, o.name, gu.length)).result
    }
```